# Shortcode doesn't working. Return error meassage

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have this code for making custom shortcode. But it returns this error message. How to overcome this error.

**[NOTE: I have also tried closing the php tag before starting the html and starting it again after ending the html]**

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\theme-dev\wp-content\themes\sportify\functions.php on line 77`

```
// Add Shortcode
    function custom_shortcode() {

    <div class="intro"> /* line no 79 */
        <div class="intro_boxes_wrap">

            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start flex-wrap">
                <?php 
                    $query = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type'     => 'intro',
                        'post_per_page' => 3,
                    ));
                    while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 
                ?>
                <!-- Intro Box -->
                <div class="intro_box d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <div class="intro_box_title"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></div>
                    <div class="intro_box_text">
                        <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
add_shortcode( 'kollol', 'custom_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is because you try to output html in php block. you have to use php end/start tags

```
// Add Shortcode
    function custom_shortcode() {
ob_start();
?>

<div class=intro> ... </div> //... exactly the code you got now 

<?php

return ob_get_clean();  //ob_get_clean() is returning everything you echoed or rendered since ob_start()
}
add_shortcode( 'kollol', 'custom_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried that way but it didn't work then. Now I find the error. I didn't use an space before and after starting and ending the html block